# positive of a function defined via integrals

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

The function is defined by the formula $$f_{a, c}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg[t^a(1+t)^{c-a-1}e^{-xt}-e^{-t}+e^{-xt}\bigg]\frac{dt}{t}$$  for all $a>0, x>0$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$. How to show that this functionn is positive? or negative?  But, I know that this function is decreasing. That is $f'_{a, c}(x)<0$ for all $a>0, x>0$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a bit with your function getting this formula

$f_{a, c}(x)=\Gamma (a) U(a,c,x)+\left(e^x-1\right) \int_0^{\infty } \dfrac{e^{-t}}{t} \, dt$

where $U(a,c,x)$ is confluent hypergeometric function.

The second part is positive because $x>0\to e^x-1>0$ and the exponential function integral is about $224.75$

$\Gamma(a)>0$ for any positive $a$

Only the parametric confluent hypergeometric function is quite a "mistery" but after many plot in *Mathematica* It looks like positive for positive $a,\;x$ and any $c$

But I can't prove it

Hope it helps